# Python script to query database and placing the file in S3 - Design issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, oop, amazon-s3, code-organization

I am writing a python script to query about 60 database tables based on a current timestamp and store those as csv file in S3 bucket. There are some global variables that I need access to like engine, aws credentials, current_time etc. I have this file currently as 60 functions each querying a table which then calls a function to write into s3.

How do I organize this code better so I won't have to call these 60 functions from the main function?

More importantly, how do I also organize this code following OOP. I am very new to this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
import (bunch of imports)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///bookdatabase.db', echo=False)
access_key = 'adasdasdasdasd'
access_id = 'asdasdasd'

def table_name():
    table_name = 'book'
    sql = "select * from book where modified_date < current_date"
    mn = pandas.read_sql(sql, engine)

    # write_to_s3

def another_table_name():
    # .....
    # etc. etc.
```

Comment: The golden rule of programming is - write the simplest code that makes it work, before making it fancy. Python developers try to write code that is "Pythonic" which means it follows the basic guidelines for Python code. There is nothing wrong with having 60, 70, or 600 functions in a program - if they are required.

Answer (score 0):

Functions that do the same thing, only with a single variance are a clue that really those actions can be combined into a better structure.

In your case, you are doing the same *thing* (calling a database, and updating a bucket), the difference is you call different databases, and read different tables.

So why not create a function like this:

```
S3_ACCESS_KEY = '....'
S3_ACCESS_ID = '....'

def export_to_s3(db_configuration):
   for db, tables in db_configuration.items():
       engine = create_engine('sqlite://{}'.format(db), echo=False)
       for table_name in tables:
           sql = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE modified_date < 
                  current_date".format(table_name)
           cursor = engine.cursor()
           cursor.execute(sql)
           for result in cursor:
               # push result to s3

db_table_names = {'bookdatabase.db': ['book'],
                  'another.db': ['fruits', 'planets']}

export_to_s3(db_table_names)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this. I actually didn't mention in the question that some of these tables require multiple conditions with lot of different fields so it can't really be simplified like you did here although I do like this idea. I guess I am more confused about how to store these values like connection to database, access keys etc and then have the function be called. In my current structure I have to type out all the functions which does not seem like a good way to code.